# Ask fabric to execute something on machines that belong to two roles

Tags: fabric

I want to execute something on all web servers of cluster1. But if I tell Fabric

```
fab -R cluster1,webserver ...
```

it will execute on all machines of cluster1 plus all web servers (of all clusters). What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be solved like this:

```
fab -R cluster1_webserver ...
```

where `cluster1_webserver` is defined in the fabfile to be this:

```python
roledefs['cluster1_webserver'] = list(
    set(roledefs['cluster1']) & set(roledefs['webserver']))
```